# Integrating D3 with Angular-cli

Tags: d3.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to integrate D3 chart library with Angular CLI. First I installed d3 with **npm install d3 --save**. Once done my node_modules looks like

[image: It added following highlighted folders to node_modules folder]

d3 version is **"d3": "^4.2.2"**.

Then I set up configuration as below.

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
    var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

    module.exports = function(defaults) {
      return new Angular2App(defaults, {
        vendorNpmFiles: [
          ......
          'd3/**/*'
        ]
      });
    };
```

**system-config.ts**

```
    "use strict";

    // SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
    // https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
    // https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

    /***********************************************************************************************
     * User Configuration.
     **********************************************************************************************/
    /** Map relative paths to URLs. */
    const map:any = {
      '@angular2-material': 'vendor/@angular2-material',
      // 'd3': 'vendor/d3'
      'd3': 'vendor/d3/build'
    };

    /** User packages configuration. */
    const materialPackages:string[] = [
      'core',
      'button',
      'icon',
      'sidenav',
      'toolbar',
      'list',
      'card'
    ];
    const packages:any = {
      'd3': {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: 'd3'
      },
    };
    materialPackages.forEach(name => {
      packages[`@angular2-material/${name}`] = {
        format: 'cjs',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        main: name
      };
    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /***********************************************************************************************
     * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
     **********************************************************************************************/
    const barrels:string[] = [
      // Angular specific barrels.
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/forms',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/router',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

      // Thirdparty barrels.
      'rxjs',

      // App specific barrels.
      'app',
      'app/shared',
      'app/bar',
      'app/chart',
      /** @cli-barrel */
    ];

    const cliSystemConfigPackages:any = {};
    barrels.forEach((barrelName:string) => {
      cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = {main: 'index'};
    });



    /** Type declaration for ambient System. */
    declare var System:any;

    // Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
    System.config({
      map: {
        '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
        'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
        'main': 'main.js',
      },
      packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
    });

    // Apply the user's configuration.
    System.config({map, packages});
```

In **app.module.ts**, I imported d3 as below.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

Then,

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, d3],
      providers: [],
      imports: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
```

Following is what my **dist** folder looks,

[image]

When I try to build the project with **ng build** it gives below error.

```
 Cannot find module 'd3'
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to add **d3 typings** to your project, d3 does not include typings and you have to get it to use the import system.

You can :

- use the [TypeScript Definition Manager](https://github.com/typings/typings) in order to import the requested typing in your project :

  `typings install dt~d3 --global --save`

  Then you will have the definition file for d3 in your typings directory.
- Refers to [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation), you can install typings by using npm :

  `npm install @types/d3 --save-dev`

After all, you should take a look to the d3 definition file to be sure that is the correct typing for the latest release of d3.